# Installing WatermelonDB from github gives "Unable to resolve module @nozbe/watermelondb/adapters/sqlite"

Tags: android, react-native, watermelondb

I am trying to compile a hello-world react-native app that has `WatermelonDB` configured. I am following the instructions given [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/offline-app-react-native-watermelondb/) and [and here](https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/Installation.html#ios-react-native) to set up the project for `Watermelon`.

I have found that if I install `WatermelonDB` using

```
yarn add @nozbe/watermelondb
```

the application launches correctly in android and iOS. But if I install from `github`:

```
yarn add https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB.git
```

I get the following error:

[image: Unable to resolve module error]

Does anyone know why installing directly from `github` results in this error when running the application?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 // add this
        multiDexEnabled true // add this
     }
}
```

add this in `dependencies`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

then `sync` after that

clean the project, build folder, gradlew and idea

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
```

also

```
rm -rf .gradle && rm -rf .idea
```